# How do you make a bot that reacts to any mention of a specific string with a list of sentences?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I managed to get my last bot to work, thanks to you people. I would like to make my bot react to a string with a list.

Example: Any sentence containing "bruh", the bot will respond with one item from a list of sentences.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you so very much, SO!

Qwertxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you mean, you want a random sentence from a list of sentences?

If so that's pretty easy:

```js
const {Client} = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client();
client.on("message", msg => {
  const list = ["no you can't say that", "yea this is not okay", "ok"];
  if(msg.content.includes("bruh")) {
   const random = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length];
   msg.channel.send(random); 
 }
});
```